# Convert html to word /excel / powerPoint with PHP

Tags: php

How to convert html to word /excel / powerpoint with PHP ?

Comment: Do you realize how complicated some of those are going to be?

Comment: TBH I don't know why one would want to degrade HTML to a format that's not properly standardized and supported on multiple platforms.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the following PHP classes:

- [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet)
- [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord)
- [PHPPresentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation)

I only used PHPExcel so far but it worked great and is easy to learn. Since all classes are from the same company I assume that they should fit your needs as well.

Comment: Just as a point of note, we're not a company, we're simply a disparate group of FOSS developers scattered around the world; but yes, the three projects are all related.

Answer (score 0):

### PHP to Word:

I think the easiest way to generate DOC files with PHP is using the [Zend Framework component phpLiveDocx](http://www.phplivedocx.org/articles/brief-introduction-to-phplivedocx/). You can load Word or Open Office templates, merge textual data and save the final document to a number of formats, such as DOC, DOCX, RTF and PDF.

Comment: But input types are only DOC, DOCX, RTF, TDX.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that @Nick answer is correct, but you do not need an external tool to do what you need, at least not for Word.

To generate a Word document simply add this code at the top of the page you want to convert.

```
<?php 
   header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word");
   header("Expires: 0");
   header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
   header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=MyReport.doc"); 
?>
```

For Excel I found this (did not test):

```
<?php
   header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=abc.xls");  
   header("Expires: 0");
   header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
   header("Cache-Control: private",false);
?>
```