# HTML to MS Word document?

Tags: php, html, linux, ms-word, doc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert html to word /excel / powerPoint with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590646/convert-html-to-word-excel-powerpoint-with-php)

I need to programatically convert HTML (created with [CK Editor](http://ckeditor.com/)) into a .doc file. I have an old RTF converter written in PHP, but it isn't working well.

I'm looking for solutions either written in PHP or a command-line program for linux/FreeBSD that I can invoke.

Comment: Several duplicates: https://www.google.com/search?q=html+to+word+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Didn't come across those in my searches, but they all seem to be .net/C#.

Comment: @mario: The accepted answer references [PHPWord](http://phpword.codeplex.com/) which makes no mention of HTML.

Comment: That "exact dupe" doesn't answer my question at all.

Comment: http://htmltodocx.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I've found this: http://www.phpdocx.com/

Comment: http://www.phpdocx.com/documentation/tutorial#plugin sounds like it just uses OpenOffice. I'm not buying software to access another piece of software I can already get for free...