# PPT to HTML convertion using PHP

Tags: php

Is there any library available in PHP to convert the MS-Power Point to HTML format? 
Can anyone list out the possible ways to achieve this conversion ?

Comment: @arielnmz How it's duplicate user want `PPT to HTML` not `HTML to PPT`

Comment: @Barmar How it's duplicate user want PPT to HTML not HTML to PPT?

Comment: I believe the libraries described there go both ways.

Comment: It's better to use an api of any sites providing the conversion.

Comment: @SonyMathew Why do you consider it is it better to use an api? From my perspective if something changes on the api side, it will break your code. I always try to avoid external dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

http://phpword.codeplex.com/

http://phppowerpoint.codeplex.com/

More info: [Convert html to word /excel / powerPoint with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590646/convert-html-to-word-excel-powerpoint-with-php)

Comment: user want `PPT to HTML` not `HTML to PPT`

Comment: Will this work for PPT to HTML ?

Comment: PhpPowerpoint does not support outputting HTML