# How to convert html to word using php?

Tags: php

I am trying to convert **HTML to MS WORD document (.doc/.docx) with PHP script**. With the available scripts from internet I am able to convert the  text of HTML to doc. But I need total html with inline css will be in my doc.I made one script

```
$html = file_get_contents('html path');
$tags = "<br>";
$test = strip_tags($page,$html);
$breaks = array("<br />","<br>","<br/>");  
$text = str_ireplace($breaks, "\r\n", $test);  
$text = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT',$text);
$handle = fopen("newdoc.doc", "w+");
fwrite($handle, $text);
fclose($handle);
```

It's working for the text content of HTML only.
But I can't add images to it is there any way to do it ? Please Help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590646/convert-html-to-word-excel-powerpoint-with-php

Comment: that's already checked . it's the same answer no image content getting converted

Comment: Why dont you use http://phpword.codeplex.com/ it allows adding images and the text styling is pretty close to css but you will have to pass the text not html, otherwise I think you can pass the image base64

Comment: well I need image content too. also when I am converting a dynamic html I can't write css externally .

Answer (score 47):

just keep following code in top of the page need to convert:

```
<? header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=Report.doc");
?>
```

Comment: This answer should have more upvotes. This require no extra software, http headers only, is fast and simple. For example, libre office (open office branch) is able to convert the html into a perfectly fine document.

Comment: MS Word is also quite successful with simple html.

Comment: After several hours of trying to get PHPword to work (to no success), I stubled upon this. I have no idea why this is not the accepted answer, and why it took me so long to find such an easy solution for simple documents.

Comment: this is the simplest solution

Comment: Is there a way to build a docx instead ?

Answer (score 4):

I would highly recommend [PHPdocx](http://www.phpdocx.com/documentation/introduction/html-to-word-PHP) as it does exactly what your asking for, but at a cost. I purchased it sometime ago and use it frequently.

```
require_once 'pathToPHPDocX/classes/CreateDocx.inc';
$docx = new CreateDocx();
$html='http://www.2mdc.com/PHPDOCX/simpleHTML_Image.html';
$docx->embedHTML($html, array('isFile' => true, 'downloadImages' => true));
$docx->createDocx('simpleHTML');
```

http://www.phpdocx.com/documentation/introduction/html-to-word-PHP

Answer (score 2):

I am currently working through something similar and have gone with

- [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord)

Huge amount of information on the site to get you started and you can style each element how you would like.

Images can be added simply with: `$section->addImage($src, [$style]);`

I would take a look. Its a bit more involved than what you are currently using, but allows you to do what you need.

Comment: well I have tried with PHPword too but for a dynamic html it's hard to use .thanks for your reply.

Comment: I am using it to generate a document that equates to anywhere from 6 - 8 pages in a word document, all of it is dynamically created HTML.

Comment: Sorry im new here and didn't mean to add that comment uncompleted. I made a parser to take my HTML and create a styles array based on its HTML tags. Works well.

Comment: can you please show me your codes ? as example please edit your answer

Comment: Cant show full codes because NDA but I am currently experimenting with I am currently experimenting with `$output =  preg_split('@(?=<)@', $html, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);` to split my HTML by tags and then working through each to build up my styles array before using something like `$section->addText(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($line)), $textArgs, $paraArgs);` to add each element.