# Export HTML (with CSS styles) as Word document (.doc or .docx)

Tags: html, css, ms-word, export, export-to-word

I am trying to export a simple page as a word document but can't seem to find any way to do this. Any method I try simply exports text with font colours but nothing else. What I want is for an export method that uses css styles properly. This is pure html, css and javascript with no back-end language in play.

I tried:

- Opening the url in Word 2016
- Exporting with chrome extension
- Used FileSaver.js and wordexport.js to export

In all 3 cases the styles are missing. In particular the fonts and content styles are ignored. Saving as pdf works perfectly. I have css print styles that are never used and even if the same styles are added directly to elements it still doesn't show up in the .doc file.

Is there any reasonable solution?

Comment: You must be using some kind of language on your server. I have to guess that that is PHP. If it is, have you done any searching yourself? I think you have. Always mention these, otherwise you get answers containing things you have already tried. In this case I found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628171/how-to-convert-html-to-word-using-php

Comment: @KIKOSoftware No, it's just pure html, css and some javascript running on apache for url rewriting.

Comment: If you save a HTML page with a .doc extension it will display fine in Word. That said, which version of Word are you targeting?

Comment: Saving html is not an option as it will not use print stylesheets and after trying it looks exactly the same as with other methods I tried. It should work in the same way that a native .doc would work, including libreoffice and similar apps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert html to word using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628171/how-to-convert-html-to-word-using-php)