# Is there any way to convert ckeditor html content to ms word document?

Tags: laravel, ckeditor

I have a Laravel project where I need to create a doc/docx document based on user input in Ckeditor. I have previously worked with PHPword where I can convert simple text input to a docx document. But the problem with ckeditor is it gives you html with inline css (which i need) and PHPWORD can not convert this to a docx.
I also tried to convert the html to word by xml but no luck. I know there is a paid tool called phpdocx but I am looking for a free solution.
Just a note, I can actually convert the html to pdf. But again, there is no solution from pdf to doc.

So, any help in converting the html to word or pdf to word?
thanks

Comment: Possibly, this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628171/how-to-convert-html-to-word-using-php

Comment: I actually did. Problem with this solution is that no internal css works, only the inline one works. Thanks for pointing it out though