# How to add page borders in a Word document with PHP

Tags: php

I want to build a tool that builds a Word document according to a form that the user will enter. So far everything works fine, but I would like to add a frame to the page, is there a way to do this?

I tried to add a border in CSS, but without success.

```
<?php
    function wordfile() {
        header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=זכד – $_POST[name].doc");

        echo "<html>";
        echo "<style>body{direction:rtl;font-family:Tahoma;} h1{font- size:14pt;}</style>";
        echo "<meta charset=UTF-8>";
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows-1252\">";

        echo "<body>";
        echo "<h1>My name - $_POST[name]</h1>";
        echo "<p>test $_POST[name].</p>";
        echo "</body>";
        echo "</html>";
   }
```

Comment: You can't send HTML when you said you're sending a Word document.

Comment: @Barmer I ran the code in a [PHPFiddle](https://phpfiddle.org), and even in this imperfect state, as long as you give the output a .doc extension, it will open in Word. It does sort of work. My document had a margin. The question is what a 'border' means, is it a margin or a line?

Comment: @sufti1323 it is right that Word is capable of interpreting HTML. But that has nothing to do with actually writing a Word-Document - that's much more complex. Maybe these links will help you:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats#Word_XML_Format_example
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590646/convert-html-to-word-excel-powerpoint-with-php

Comment: @KIKOSoftware line. A design frame that surrounds the text.